# I am using Bootstrap portfolio section, want to remove 'ALL' first tab and make the category selected

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this [template](http://webagate.com/demos/alia/plusone-onepage-responsive-website-template/light-version/nav-1/index.html)

You can scroll down to WORK section which is the portfolio section filterable.

The already selected option is "ALL" and that shows all the items. I want to get rid of it and make one of the other tabs active.

I tried removing the tab and add class 'selected' to one of the other tabs which make it look active but it's still showing 'ALL' items and not just the active tab unless I click on any other tab and select it back.

I'm not too good with java script so an easy instructions will be really appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trigger the `click event` too while you make any tabs active like one below:

```
$('[data-option-value=".web"]').trigger('click');
```

Run the above code in `console` of the link given by you and you can see the changes. You can choose any of the tab to be active.

Comment: Glad it helped.. Happy coding.. :)